# How to delete rows automatically in google sheets based off conditional formatting row colors?

Tags: function, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a google sheets page that is printing responses from a google forms page to it. The purpose of the form is to be used periodically to update your information on the form. I have conditional formatting set up where once someone's name appears twice in the B column, the cell turns #f4c7c3 light red. I am trying to figure out how to set up a function of some sorts to detect when a cell turns red and delete the row it is in. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Detecting background color change is somewhat tricky, and adding an automated delete makes it even more complicated, since `onChange()` trigger only recogznizes manual inputs, but it is doable. I have a similar code, but I used it to sum every cell of a color in the row. Also, as someone's answer said, you'll most definetly need a script, since there's no prebuilt function for it, so even for a custom function you'll need to code it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that functions can delete rows. Unless you're interested in writing a script, it may be possible to set up a second table using IF functions to check for unique values.

Comment: I'd be willing to write out a script if that's what it takes. Just not sure how to go about it.

Comment: I found this link from a few years back:

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/75528/conditional-deleting-in-google-spreadsheets